# Drill through in SSRS in Report Server using the expressions

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, power-bi-report-server, drillthrough

I've my reports previously on SharePoint site.
I recently deployed my reports to the Report Server.
In the reports there're expressions on the URL Actions part in Text Box properties where expressions have been applied based on the parameters values.
After deploying my reports to the report server and clicking on one of the value where actions have been applied i get the error.

Error:

> The item 'BC/Report/get.rdl' cannot be found. (rsItemNotFound)

I've tried placing the link of the report directly in the expressions but that's not working either. I think there needs some review in the expression.

Expressions looks like this:

```
= IIF(Parameters!ForEmail.Value <> 
TRUE,Globals!ReportServerUrl,Parameters!ReportURLSub.Value) & "?" & 
Globals!ReportFolder & "/get.rdl"
```

Thank you in Advance and sorry if explanation is not enough.

Comment: It looks as though the url is not formed correctly. Try showing the url in a textbox and copying directly into a browser to test it.

Answer (score 0):

did you tried static url per hand in browser? does it work.

If yes try adding this parameters as `Parameters!ReportURLSub.Value)` in Textbox and see if it results desired result.

Also check if `Globals!ReportServerUrl` returns correct value

If yes can create this url whith your parameters in a Textbook  static and see what result you get.

If all these steps pass then move to your last step, creating as a Action.